# Best practices for storing image reference in a database

Tags: php, database, image

I'm designing a page that will contain different image sizes per image uploaded.

```
For example an image can be:
original: whatever a user uploads
large: 718x405
medium: 344x194
small: 125x70
square: 238x238
```

In the past, in mysql, I've just had the fields called image_id, image_name and then in code I'd reference the locations of these images:

```
Example from my past:
/images/gallery/large/some_image.jpg
/images/gallery/square/some_image.jpg
```

I've seen other systems do things like:

```
/images/gallery/some_image-718x405.jpg
/images/gallery/some_image-238x238.jpg
```

What are some best practices for creating a database for images, aside from the basic idea of having the images in their own table. I'm asking more when you are dealing with multiple sizes of the same image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with saving image as flat files and keeping only image_id and image_name in db.

```
/images/<image_id>/original
/images/<image_id>/<width>_<height>
```

And serving those file out with mod_rewrite and PHP with what ever URL "format" you prefer. Using some sort of cache (file, memcache) for matching image_name to image_id to avoid unnecessary DB connections is good here if you need performance.

Remember to do session_write_close before serving the image if you have PHP sessions with the same script otherwise all other images would wait while one image is loading.

When image is deleted you would have only one directory to clear and delete.